# Delete a .txt file after it's closed?

Tags: file, powershell, delete-file, notepad

I want to delete a file after it's been closed.

Example:

```
$content | Out-File info.txt
Invoke-Item info.txt
```

This opens the file info.txt with the content of `$content`.

Now all I want to do is, when this file is closed, delete it.

Any idea how to do this? I supose I need to do something like check if info.txt is open, if not then run `Remove-Item info.txt`?

Right now I use this "dirty" solution which is force deleting the file after 3 seconds, giving it time to open in Notepad:

```
Start-Sleep -s 3
Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue info.txt
```

It remains open in notepad for viewing even though it doesn't exist anymore and when I close the file it's already deleted so it kinda works but I'm still looking for a proper way to check if file is closed before deleting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Start-Process Notepad.exe U:\test.txt -Wait
Remove-Item U:\test.txt
```

Comment: Ah yes, wait! I should've expected that :) Thank you so much it works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm limited to replying in an 'answer' because of my reputation.

Basically, my comment would have been "Does this need to be opened in a text file?"

My alternate suggestions would be to do maybe one of the following instead

```
$content | Out-GridView
```

Or maybe

```
$content | Format-Table
```

You should still see all the data, and still be able to copy data from it without saving a file anywhere that then needs deleting.

Would this be acceptable?

Comment: Good solution however the txt file provides the perfect formatting so it's needed in this case. Thank you!